# Criterion for being in a non-orientable 3 manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, orientation, non-orientable-surfaces

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of orientability as an *intrinsic* property of a manifold. Assume I'm in some (3-dim) manifold for which I'd like to decide its orientability; what could I do in that case? I guess this setting is sufficient to avoid thinking with immersions/embeddings.

My attempts so far:

- Comparing to the 2D case. If a 2D object travels along the Möbius strip, it would appear flipped (left and right) when it's back to its original location.

  But that still sounds abstract. What would I perceive if I travel around in a 3-manifold and come back? Maybe things suddenly look mirrored, I guess, but not sure. And I see no reason why it has to be left-right (instead of upside-down, since that's also perpendicular to my travel curve).
- I did find some hints in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977603/understanding-orientability-of-surfaces); the above is similar to the idea of [the second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1977705/437222) there. Another idea is to observe counter-clockwise-ness, mentioned in the comments of [the first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1977644/437222). Neither of them is sufficiently detailed to make me understand, so I have to ask this separate question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are round-trips after which everything looks mirrored. But in general, in a differentiable 3-manifold, there is no way for you to decide whether a left-right-flip or an up-down-flip occurred, because there is no canonical way for you to fix an up-direction during your travel. This might change when you add a [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics)) (I am no expert, so let's wait for other "opinions").

Comment: the straight answer: the three manifold ought to have a solid Klein-bottle or not. To get some intuition on the solid Klein-bottle one studies the cartesian product $M\dot{o}\times I$, of the Möbius band by an interval.

Comment: If our space where NOT orientable, you could not make any difference between your left and your right hand. A manifold is NOT orientable if after a certain trip in this manifold, and coming back to your origibnal position your left hand is what your left hand was.